# Symfony/Twig localizeddate not working in server PROD

Tags: symfony, twig

I used the `localizeddate` twig filter. Locally the date is in French but on the production server the date is in English. I have good in `service.yml`:

```
twig.extension.intl:
    class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

However the problem is still then. The locale of the `parameters.yml` is in FR. Do you have any idea of ​​the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When everything works fine in dev environment and not in prod, then check if you have to have PHP intl extension installed/enabled on the production server.

On Linux machines you can install it this way:

```
apt-get install php7.0-intl / apt-get install php5.0-intl
```

On Windows machines uncomment in php.ini this line:

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

Restart the Apache and do not forget to clear the cache on prod...